# CSS responsive max-height not working in safari/laptop?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have  this CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    body{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

This hides the page when it gets to 500px (just to test it), works fine in my browsers on windows PC, when I try on my MacBook Pro in Safari it doesn't seem to detect it, how can I get this to work properly? I cant find much on it on google

Comment: As @jackJoe says, more code is needed really. Where does your query sit in regards to the rest of your css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [tested it](http://jsfiddle.net/HNf9M/) and it's working fine on Safari(Mac) as well.

```
div{
    background: #ddd;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    div{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1IDo.png). Though there's a bug with Safari(iPad/iPhone). You might love to read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html).

Answer (score 1):

That works in safari, I just tested it to make sure.

The only thing that is missing in your question is the position of that query in regards to the properties/class you would like to change.

In other words, place it at the end and it will work.

Example:
This tells the browser to hide the body when the browser height is smaller than 500px:

```
body {
    display: block; 
}
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    body{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you had it the other way around the last `body` definition would make the media query useless.

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
    body{
        display: none;
    }
}
body {
    display: block; 
}
```